# trying to install vue cli using npm install -g @vue/cli but this error occurs

Tags: vue.js

I am trying to install vue cli using npm install -g @vue/cli but this error occurs:

```
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/joi@15.1.1: joi is leaving the @hapi organization and moving back to 'joi' (https://github.com/sideway/joi/issues/2411)
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/bourne@1.3.2: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/topo@3.1.6: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/address@2.1.4: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated @hapi/hoek@8.5.1: This version has been deprecated and is no longer supported or maintained
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm ERR! Response timeout while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/typescript (over 30000ms)

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\umage\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-10-17T16_20_00_242Z-debug.log
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: Is it possible that your network connection is shaky and disconnected while installing?

Comment: i think network connection is not the problem